# I called Paypal subscription API which returns success message but don't see any active subscription in the Paypal dashboard

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to create Paypal subscription through its Rest API using live client and secret.
The API returns success message. The GET subscription API returns the active subscription created, however I don't see any active subscription in my Paypal dashbaord.
Paypal support says the subscription ID does not exist.
Has anyone encountered such issue with Paypal API?
I have attached API JSON response and snapshot herewith.

```
{
"plans": [
    {
        "id": "P-4UJ45561KJ704964LMJ2QDZQ",
        "product_id": "PROD-4EX86934CR7151923",
        "name": "Certified business economist IHK | VO 2022",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "description": "The business economist IHK is divided into the following five subjects with the new examination regulations 2022",
        "usage_type": "LICENSED",
        "create_time": "2022-05-06T11:09:26Z",
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/P-4UJ45561KJ704964LMJ2QDZQ",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET",
                "encType": "application/json"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"total_items": 1,
"total_pages": 1,
"links": [
    {
        "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans?product_id=PROD-4EX86934CR7151923&page_size=2&page=1",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET",
        "encType": "application/json"
    }
]
```

}

[image: Get active subscription]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, everything in your question shows creating a plan. A plan is not a subscription, it is the cycle details to be able to create a subscription.

Secondly, creating a subscription still will not do anything unless a payer signs in to *approve* it. For a payer to approve a subscription, use a PayPal button. This is detailed in the [Subscriptions Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/).

Note that the `createSubscription` function can create a subscription for approval itself, by passing it an object with a `plan_id` (and optionally a `plan` object to override some part of that plan_id). This is the most simple method.

Alternatively, the subscription can be created via API, at a route on your server which that function will fetch when the button is clicked. Something like:

```js
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID_GOES_HERE&amp;vault=true&amp;intent=subscription"></script>

  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

  <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          label:'subscribe'  //Optional text in button
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
          return fetch('/path/on/your/server/paypal/subscription/create/', {
              method: 'post'
          }).then(function(res) {
              return res.json();
          }).then(function(serverData) {
              console.log(serverData);
              return serverData.id;
          });
      },

      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      /*  Optional: At this point, notify your server of the activated subscription...

          fetch('/path/on/your/server/paypal/subscription/activated/' + data.subscriptionID , {
              method: 'post'
          }).then(function(res) {
              return res.json();
          }).then(function(serverData) {
              //
          });
      */
          //You could additionally subscribe to a webhook for the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED event (just in case), as well as other future subscription events
          //Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions

          // Show a message to the buyer, or redirect to a success page
          alert('You successfully subscribed! ' + data.subscriptionID);
      }

    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more question though. Once a user sign in manually to approve monthly subscription, does he require to sign in manually again for the next cycle billing?

Comment: No, only initially.